Proving that the group G contains an element of order p if p divides the order of G
This is from Lemma 13.6 of the Abstract Algebra textbook by Judson. Here, let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$. If $p$ is a prime that divides $n$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.
Here we are using proof by induction. If $n=1$ it is trivial. Suppose that the lemma is true for all groups of order $k$, where $k<n$.
The book considers two different cases. First case, $G$ has no proper nontrivial subgroups. This case is trivial and I understand it. Second case, $G$ contains a nontrivial proper subgroup $H$. If $p| |H|$,we are done by induction. If not, we know that $H$ is a normal subgroup, and $p$ must divide $G/H$. By induction, $G/H$ contains an element $aH$ of order $p$. Therefore, $H=(aH)^{p}=a^p H$, and $a^p \in H$ but $a \notin H$. Everything up till this point is clear. Then the book says, if $|H|=r$, then $p$ and $r$ are relatively prime. I don't really understand this. I was thinking if they are not relatively prime, there is probably some $d>1$ such that $d=gcd(p,r)$. Then maybe $a^d \in H$ as well and that is a contradiction. I don't know if this is the case or not and I can't verify it either.
Furthermore, it is obvious that $(a^r)^p=(a^p)^r=1$. The book makes the claim that $a^r$ has order $p$, and it argues that it is sufficient to show that $a^r \neq 1$. Why is this the case? Even if $a^r \neq 1$, it is still possible to have some $q<p$ such that $(a^r)^q=1$. Why is this sufficient?

This question is similar to: Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and let $p$ be a prime that divides order of $G$. then $G$ has an element of order $p$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The doubts expressed in that post are not the ones here, so I would not call it a duplicate even though both ask about the same argument.

Remember that we are assuming that $p$ does not divide $|H|=r$. Because $p$ is prime, if it does not divide $r$, then it is relatively prime to $r$.
Also, we are assuming that $aH$ has order $p$ in $G/H$. So $p$ is the smallest positive integer such that $(aH)^p=1H$, i.e., the smallest positive integer such that $a^p\in H$. So, no, there can be no smaller $d\gt 1$ with $a^d\in H$.
By Lagrange's Theorem, $(a^p)^r=1$. So $(a^r)^p=1$.
Now the key observation that you are missing is this:

If $x$ is an element of a group, $n>1$ is an integer, and $x^n=1$, then the order of $x$ divides $n$.

(The proof of this: let $s$ be the order. Dividing $s$ by $n$ with remainder, $n=qs+r$, $0\leq r\lt s$. Then $1=x^n = x^{qs+r} = (x^s)^qx^r = x^r$. But $s$ is the smallest positive integer such that $x^s=1$, and $0\leq r\lt s$; so $r=0$ and $s$ divides $n$).
So if $(a^r)^p=1$, the order of $a^r$ must divide the prime $p$, and so is either $1$ or $p$. It can only be $1$ if $a^r=1$, so if $a^r\neq 1$, then it must be the case that the order is exactly $p$. Can't be anything else.
